# NSNumbers being added as values to NSMutableDictionary become nulls

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a piece of code that constructs a dictionary of objects as keys and operation codes (like add/update/remove) as values.

Recently, either with iOS 6, or with the arrival of "zee Germans", it broke. Values are constructed, and occasionally added, but most of the time I get a dictionary full of (null) values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < newArray.count; i++)
{
    if (![oldArray containsObject:[newArray objectAtIndex:i]])
    {
        NSNumber *opNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)kInsertOperation];
        [_operationsForRows setObject:opNumber forKey:[newArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    else ...
}
```

I've already decorated the code with intermediate variables and explicit casting of enum value to int, and grew even more confused. Printing out the resulting dictionary gives:

```
{
"<Order: 0x8aad980>" = (null);
"<Order: 0x8aad7a0>" = (null);
}
```

Can anyone explain, what am I missing here? The dictionary shouldn't even be able to hold nulls, should it?

This code is under ARC.

NSMutableDictionary was initialized on the main thread, but used exclusively on a single secondary thread.

Sometimes, an object or two would be added correctly. Say, 10%. What I've tried since:

- I've moved dictionary initialization to the same thread as usage. Wow, 90-95% of objects are added correctly, but still a null here and there.
- I've saved all possible NSNumbers in class fields. With both dictionary and numbers created on main thread, 0% success rate, lower than I started with.
- Using current-thread-initialized dictionary and main-thread numbers in class fields, I get to 90-95% again...

Cry, cry... Looks like a rewrite of the whole place.

Comment: Is your `NSMutableDictionary` was allocated before using?

Comment: Yes. It was allocated, and it prints out as a dictionary. Nils print out differently...

Comment: hmm...the code looks fine. Since it's saying that the objects are null in the dictionary, maybe something is wrong with kInsertOperation. Can you hardcode opNumber to be 5? See if it will print all 5's, or still all null.

Comment: The code assigns values 1 and 2 in my tests. Enum values are correctly cast to ints, and NSNumbers made from them look fine... Just never make it into the dictionary. I've tried to move [[alloc]init] to the same thread - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of NSDictionary.

The difference between the two being that you can modify `NSMutableDictionary` after initialisation whereas `NSDictionary` is set.

Comment: If you'd be so kind to look at the title, that's what I began with. Are you telling me I **can** insert keys into an immutable dictionary, but can't insert values? Also, is there a way to send "setObject:forKey:" to an NSDictionary and not have it blow up?

Comment: Sorry I missed that in the title as you mention `NSDictionary` in the content. You can't modify the NSDictionary after you have initialised which is why you use `NSMutableDictionary'. With 'NSMutableDictionary' you can add both keys and values after initialization

Comment: And when you use NSDictionary, you can't even run the code snippet above without crashing, much less have it work correctly before, as stated in the question.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to use NSDictionary in your snippet. NSMutableDictionary is the way to go. Could your problem be something to do with memory management changes or something to do with the ARC?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to have NSDictionary in my snippet. That is what I'm trying to explain to you in my comments. My problem could be something with memory and ARC. That is why I am asking this question and mentioning ARC - I can not find the answer myself.

Comment: Ok sorry I think we have had our wires crossed a bit. It doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong in that respect but would be worth checking your variables and NSLogging them as they go through because your dictionary conditions could be wrong or something is going wrong in the loop. Your code looks fine in the respect of memory management